Why is my command syntax not correct for Sims 4 installed on an external drive?
I had an external drive that recently got corrupted due to bad files and I got a new one to try and save my Sims 4 game, but whatever I did before to try and make sure my mods kept working suddenly no longer works.
This is the code I used before, modified for my present hard drive
MKLINK /J “%Owner%\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4” “D:\The Sims 4”

I have retyped it in various different ways to try and make it work, but it keeps saying the syntax command is not correct, and I truly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I don't understand computers, I don't know how to code, so if there's any simple answer to my issue, I'd greatly appreciate it.
I hate playing the game without mods, and I don't have any room on my internal drive for all of the packs I have.

Quotation marks in scripts must be "straight" ASCII quotes: " instead of “ ”.
The %Owner% environment variable looks custom, and is not present on any of my Windows systems by default – something needs to actually set it before the command. Otherwise you probably want to use %USERPROFILE% instead (or type out the full C:\Users\myname).
Both the %var% syntax for environment variables, as well as the mklink command as a whole, are specific to the traditional Cmd.exe shell and will not be recognized by PowerShell.
So if you're in PowerShell (PS C:\> is shown), then either run cmd first, or prefix the command with cmd /c, or try PowerShell's near-equivalent New-Item to create the link.
